# Do I need to delete point in plugin class in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Now, I perfect my question.The pointer m_Core will be initialized and GetCore() will be called first for sure.The most I concerned is the document said root component will be deleted automatically when QPluginLoader is fully unloaded,and I don't know how Qt process the memory when Qt destruct QPluginloader and instances. If Qt will delete the Object before the destruction of QPluginLoader, I don't need to free it manually. In fact, when I invalid the `delete m_Core`, Qt reports no err, if I valid it, Qt will report segment fault, so Qt must destruct Mplugin class before call ~Mplugin() function.

The m_Core is derived class of QWidget:
SF_Core.h

```
#include <QWidget>
class SF_Core:public QWidget
{
    SF_Core(QWidget* parent):QWidget(parent){}
    ~SF_Core(){}
};
```

and I use it through QPluginLoader in my project like this:

```
mainWindow.h
#include "MInterface.h"
#include "SF_Core.h"
#include <QWidget>
class MainWindow:public QWidget
{
   Q_Object
   MainWindow();
   ~MainWindow();
private:
   MInterface* interface;
   QObject* plugin;
   MCore* core;
}
mainWindow.cpp
void mainWindow::mainWindow()
{
   QPluginLoader loader("SF_Core.dll");
   plugin = loader.instance(); 
   interface = qobject_cast<MInterface* >(plugin);
   core = interface->GetCore();
}
```

I have a plugin class derived from MIngerface class in Qt program, and override the function GetCore() in MIngerface.

```
#include "SF_Core.h"
class Mplugin:public QObject,MInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID INTERFACE_ID)
    Q_INTERFACES(MInterface)
public:
    Mplugin();
    ~Mplugin(){
      delete m_Core;
    }
    SF_Core* GetCore(){
    m_Core = new SF_Core;
    return m_Core;
    }    
private:
    SF_Core* m_Core;
};
```

In main program, I load the plugin by QPluginLoader,and use instance() to get the root component. When I terminated the program, it crashed.I found the err came from the sentence `delete m_Core;` If I don't delete m_Core, will it cause memory leak?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: are you sure that GetCore was called at least once? maybe it crashed because it was never called, and m_Core contained uninitialized trash (it's not a smart pointer and you're not zeroing it out in the ctor). Another possibility is that GetCore was called and the ownership of 'SF_Core' was transferred to some q-component that destroyed it for you when app was closing, and then your delete was trying to delete it second time. But which of that is your case, toss a coin.

Comment: I recommend to either use `final` or to declare the destructor `virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial short answer**

Keeping in mind the principle of ownership, most probably yes: it will cause memory leak.

Also, consider that each call to `GetCore` will allocate a new instance and create memory leak.

However, without having a full example, it is difficult to understand how `SF_Core` is used, especially if it ownership is transferred or not.

---

**Stack variable fix**

What if you use an internal stack value? (Not the best practice, however to publish internal properties)

```
SF_Core* GetCore()
{
    return &m_Core;
}    
private:
SF_Core m_Core;
```

---

**Alternative using shared_ptr**

An alternative is to use smart pointer (which I highly recommend over raw pointers whenever possible):

```
using SfCorePtr = std::shared_ptr<SF_Core>;
SfCorePtr GetCore()
{
    if (!m_CorePtr)
    {
        m_CorePtr = std::make_shared<SF_Core>(); // Lazy creation
    }
    return m_CorePtr;
}    
private:
SfCorePtr m_Core;
```

Hint: to be even more pedantic, the use of `std::weak_ptr` allows to give access to a smart pointer without providing it ownership: If `GetCore` return a `weak_ptr`, the ownership of m_Core is keep inside this object and the ownership stay in a tree-shape instead of graph-shape.

---

**Minimal fix**

Otherwise, just fixing your code:

```
#include "Mcore.h"
class Mplugin:public QObject,MInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID INTERFACE_ID)
    Q_INTERFACES(MInterface)
public:
    Mplugin();
    virtual ~Mplugin(){
        delete m_Core;
    }
    SF_Core* GetCore(){
        if (nullptr == m_Core){
            m_Core = new SF_Core;
        }
        return m_Core;
    }    
private:
    SF_Core* m_Core=nullptr;
};
```

Comment: I made a quick search and found no documentation about that `SF_Core`, also Qt usually prefix it classes with `Q` or `Qt`; so I expect this class to be custom from the OP. In any case, I followed your recommendation and fixed the answer for the different situations.

Comment: I update my question,how should I write my destructor of Mplugin class?

Comment: oh,I mean would you please tell me what Qt will do after QPluginLoader is destructed, and when Qt free the memory of instances created by instance() function. Return value of instance() is a QObject pointer of root component, and is assigned to a private member in mainwindow , the pointer plugin.According my understand,when  plugin pointer is deleted,the memory allocated by instance() is freed,so I need to delete plugin and m_Core in my destructor of mainWindow, am I right? Thank you very much for your help!!!